# Is fear the only factor which makes Devils powerful?

Tags: chainsaw-man

In episode three of Chainsaw-Man, Makima explains how fears and phobias give certain devils strength amongst other devils. This works out seeing that people fearing guns makes the Gun Devil so powerful and huge.

[image: Gun-Devil]

Another example of a devil which becomes omnipotently powerful because of fear is the "Darkness Devil" because, go figure, a significant percentage of the world population is afraid of the dark.

[image: Darkness-Devil]

An instance where the situation is reversed when Bucky the "Chicken Devil" is introduced. He claims to be incredibly weak, so weak that even a common cat would tear him apart.

[image: Bucky the Chicken-Devil]

Given this, fear seems to be the overarching power boost for devils. But does that apply to Denji? Eventually Chainsaw Man become a popular hero amongst Japanese society, with some fans and haters.

[image: p.g. 2 Chapter 93 "Chainsaw-Man"]

With several people idolizing him rather than fearing him he still manages to become more powerful. So, my big question is what if fear isn't all that makes devils powerful, but their notoriety in general?